# VBA: Clicking the 'Google Search' button in internet explorer

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to fix my code that web scrapes addresses using internet explorer with VBA. The most recent update has messed my code up and I am unable to find a way to click on the 'Google Search' button. I did not have a problem with this before since my code had previously clicked on the magnifying glass icon but the new update removed that icon.

I am fairly new to VBA but I have been searching the internet to solutions for the problem by trying to use IHTMLElementCollection's to access the specific element that is within multiple class name but I am still getting no where. The first block of code (elm1) inputs the address into the search bar of google. The rest of the code I have tried to use to access and click the 'Google Search' button:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
URL = "https://www.google.com/"
ie.Navigate URL
Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

'Trying to get google search button for elm2
Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument
Dim oElement As Object
Dim objDS As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim objLSBB As IHTMLElementCollection

Do While ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"


Set elm1 = ie.document.getElementsByName("q")
    For n = 0 To elm1.Length - 1
        If elm1(n).Value = "" Then
            elm1(n).Focus
            elm1(n).Value = endCell.End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).Value & " Map"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next n

'Set elm2 = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
'elm2.Click
'Set elm2 = ie.document.querySelector("[class='ds']")
'elm2.Click

    
'Set list2 = ie.document.querySelector(".ds")
'Debug.Print list2.Children(0).innerText

'Set objDS = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("ds")
'For i = 0 To objDS.Length - 1
  '  Debug.Print objDS(i).innerHTML
    
'Next





'Set objLSBB = objDS(0).getElementsByClassName("lsbb")
'Debug.Print objLSBB.Children(0).innerText

'Set objDS = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("lsbb")
'For Each elm In objDS
'    Debug.Print elm.innerHTML
    
    
'Next
```

I have been able to access the 'Google Search' button correctly but for some reason, .Click will not work when trying to click on the button. This confuses me since the button has type="submit". I am also posting a screenshot of the html from google as a reference.

[Google html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFJkQ.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Is [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69483188/vba-clicking-the-google-search-button-in-internet-explorer/69492228#69492228) helpful to deal with the issue? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the 'Google Search' button using its name `btnG`. You can refer to my sample code below, it works well:

```
Sub LOADIE()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate ("https://www.google.com")

Do Until IE.readyState = 4
   DoEvents
Loop

IE.document.getElementsByName("q")(0).Value = "Map"
IE.document.getElementsByName("btnG")(0).Click

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]